# Why I've got an error when comparing two same object : 'Expected PostModel({ }) to be PostModel({ }).' in my test

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test an Angular service who call an API, an compare the response. But before I just wanted to compare the global object without data. And I've got an error int this part of my code  `const resp: PostModel = service.setPost('data'); mockRequest.flush(resp); mockHttp.verify();` And I dont undestand bacause for me they are same objects.
Here is

**My post-service.ts**

```
  public addPost(newPost: PostModel): Observable<PostModel> {
     return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + 'add', newPost).pipe( map( response => {
     console.log('response: ', response);
     return this.setPost(response);
   }));
 }


 public setPost(data: any): PostModel{
    let post: PostModel= new PostModel();
    /**
    post.id = data.id;
    post.author = data.userId;
    post.title = data.title;
    post.content = data.content;
    post.description = data.description;
    post.img.push(data.img);
    post.isHorror = !data.forChild;
    */
    return post;
  }
```

and

**My post-service.spec.ts**

```
import {inject, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {HttpClientTestingModule,HttpTestingController,} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import PostModel from '../models/Post.model';
import { PostService } from './post.service';

describe('PostService', () => {
  let mockHttp: HttpTestingController;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [PostService]
    });
    mockHttp = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should be created', inject( [PostService], (service: PostService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  it('shoul call post and return PostModel', inject(
    [PostService], (service: PostService) => {
      const newPost: PostModel = new PostModel();
      service.addPost(newPost).subscribe((response => {
        expect(response).toBe(newPost);
      }));

      const mockRequest = mockHttp.expectOne('api/story/post/add');
      expect(mockRequest.request.method).toEqual('POST');
      /** const data = this.generatePostMock(); */
      const resp: PostModel = service.setPost('data');
      mockRequest.flush(resp);
      mockHttp.verify();
    }
  ));
  
  generatePostMock(): PostModel {
    let mock: PostModel = new PostModel();
    mock.id = 1;
    mock.author = 12;
    mock.title = 'title';
    mock.content = 'content';
    mock.description = 'description';
    mock.img.push('../assets/img/hell_dog.png');
    mock.isHorror = true;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not comparing the same object but identical objects, hence you have to use `toEqual(newPost)` instead of `toBe(newPost)` as follows:

```
expect(response).toEqual(newPost);
```

> from [Jasmine Matchers](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.6/matchers) documentation:
>
> **`toBe(expected)`**: expect the actual value to be === to the expected value.
>
> **`toEqual(expected)`**: expect the actual value to be equal to the expected, using deep equality comparison.